# Prove that there will always be two integers selected that have a common divisor larger than 1.

Tags: combinatorics

We select 11 positive integers that are less than 29 at random.

Prove that there will always be two integers selected that have a common divisor larger than 1.

Comment: **To get the best possible answers, you should explain what your thoughts on the problem are**. That way, people won't tell you stuff you already know, and they can write answers at an appropriate level; also, people tend to be more willing to help if you show that you've tried the problem yourself. Lastly, some may consider your post rude because it is phrased as a command, not a request for help, so please consider rewriting it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's try to build a set of $11$ numbers no two of which have a common divisor greater than $1$. We will see that we **must** fail.

We can use at most one of the $14$ numbers $2.4.6.8.\dots,28$. So we need at least $10$ numbers chosen from the $14$ odd numbers.

We can have at most one of the $5$ numbers $3.9.15.21.27$.

That leaves $9$ numbers not yet mentioned, from which we must select $9$. So if we have successfully avoided using two even numbers, and $2$ numbers divisible by $3$, we must among others select $5$ and $25$. But these have a common divisor greater than $1$.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** It suffices to show that you will select two numbers that have a single common prime factor.  How many primes are there between $1$ and $29$?

Answer (score 2):

There are only 9 primes $\{2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23\}$ less than 29. Every number greater than 1 and less than 29 must have at least one of these primes as a factor. Then any list of 11 numbers greater than 0 and less than 29 must have a repeated prime.